# Отсутствует перевод уведомления при улучшении правки без её изменения

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Если в предлагаемых правках нажать Улучшить правку и затем Сохранить, ничего не изменяя, то выскочит непереведённое уведомление:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как вы это обнаружили? (Смотрю подозревающим взглядом) :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin попробовал изменить комментарий к правке, не меняя саму правку.

Answer (score 4):

вариант, предложенный @Discord-ом:

- `Предложенные вами изменения совпадают с правкой, ожидающей проверки.`
- `Предложенные вами изменения совпадают с правкой, [ожидающей проверки]($url$).`

Comment: Второй вариант немного отличается от исходного вариант – нет призыва к действию. Что думаете по поводу `Предложенные вами изменения совпадают с правкой, ожидающей проверки. [Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с правкой]($url$).`?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, я думаю, имеет смысл добавить ещё один общий ответ.

Comment: Готово. Пока выставил строки из этого ответа. Если в будущем «расширенный вариант» получит больше голосов, то поменяем обратно.

Answer (score 2):

- [tx:8653](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/82273592) `Your changes are identical to a pending edit.` — *перевода нет*

предлагаю такой перевод: `Предложенные вами изменения идентичны правке, ожидающей проверки.`

---

- [tx:8654](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/82318750) `Your changes are identical to a pending edit, [please review it]($url$).` — *перевода нет*

предлагаю такой перевод: `Предложенные вами изменения идентичны правке, [ожидающей проверки]($url$).`

Comment: Как славянофил, "идентичны" я бы заменил на "совпадают с".

Comment: @Discord, так напишите ответ с вашим вариантом, для голосования.

Comment: А смысл? Если разрыв 12+ часов, то победит первый вариант из двух более-менее равных.

Comment: @Discord, добавил вариант ответа.

Comment: @Squidward а вот и нет )

Answer (score 1):

- `Предложенные вами изменения совпадают с правкой, ожидающей проверки.`
- `Предложенные вами изменения совпадают с правкой, ожидающей проверки. [Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с правкой]($url$).`